# Magento: Login and redirect to account page from outside magento

Tags: magento

I am using this below code to login and redirect to account page:

```
<?php
include('store/app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

if($_POST && $_POST['login']['username'] && $_POST['login']['password']){
    $email = $_POST['login']['username'];
    $password = $_POST['login']['password'];
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');

        try {

            $log = $session->login($email, $password);
            $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($session->getCustomer());

            $customer_id = $session->getCustomerId();

            $send_data["success"] = true;
            $send_data["message"] = "Login Success";
            $send_data["customer_id"] = $customer_id;

            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customer_id);
            Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start();

        }catch (Exception $ex) {
            $send_data["success"] = false;
            $send_data["message"] = $ex->getMessage();
        }

}else {
    $send_data["success"]=false;
    $send_data["message"]="Enter both Email and Password";
}

echo json_encode($send_data);

?>
```

And then on file from where I am making ajax request, I am using this code:

```
if(data.success){
    window.location = "http://domain.com/store/customer/account/"
}
```

But it always show user as logout, though I do get correct customer id as well as success.

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = strip_tags($_GET["login"]);
$password = strip_tags($_GET["psw"]);

function loginUser( $email, $password ) {

    umask(0);
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    Mage::app('default');
    Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->website_id = $websiteId;
    $customer->setStore($store);
    try {
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        if($session->login($email, $password)){ return true;} else { };
    }catch(Exception $e){
      return $e->getMessage();
    }


      }



if (loginUser($email,$password) == 1) {
echo ".. user loged as ".Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getName()."<br>";} else {
 //bad things goes here
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what I am missing in my code? Because I am able to get customer name but still when I visit the store, it shows user still not logged in..

Comment: I think you are not exactly logged-in, only calling session stored info, (created browser login session and stored in magento session) for more reasons. First you must use session start. Second, you must set store and must have admin session, load magento core session controller. etc etc... Just use function in my answer and it will work ...

Comment: I do get the message ".. user loged as USERNAME" but still when I try to visit the store account page, it redirects me to login page.

Comment: -this funcion is used on many instalations and works on site.  No errors reported. I guess, the issuewill be in redirections. Make sure you cleared old sessions in VAR folder and make sure if redirection is issue with login, and not with rewrites configuration, or anything else

Answer (score 1):

In my case Martin's code works if I change the session name

```
session_name('frontend');
session_start();
```

If you leave the session name alone it defaults PHPSESSID which isn't the same as that created by Magento on a manual login and didn't work in my install. That may vary, try logging in manually and check your cookie names.

session_name documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php